# How can I force focus on the terminal after running a run configuration in IntelliJ?

Tags: terminal, intellij-idea

I have a run configuration in IntelliJ which runs a python script expecting some user input.

It's all working as planned, however, the user has to click on the terminal window to set the focus so that the input is received (else it just edits the currently opened file)

Is there a way to force the focus of the terminal after the user clicks on the green arrow for the "run configuration"?

Alternatively, a dialogue popup would suffice.

Comment: Is it problem to use shortcut ?

Comment: @AntonDozortsev What do you mean?

Comment: You can move focus to Terminal tab using keyboard shortcut

Comment: @AntonDozortsev Ah, is that the only way? I want to make it easier for the user.